# Write table with new line instead of NA

Tags: r

So, I have a data frame, which I formed by combining lists of varying lengths by extending the shorter ones with `NA`'s.

**Example:**

```
           [,1]    [,2]     [,3]  [,4]   [,5]     [,6]   
PAHS.147A  "TNF"   "TRAF6"  NA    NA     NA       NA     
PAHS.122A  "TRAF6" "TRIM25" NA    NA     NA       NA     
PAHS.012A  "TRAF3" "TRAF4"  NA    NA     NA       NA     
PAHS.3012A "CD40"  "CD40LG" "CD5" "CD70" "CDKN1A" "CEBPB"
PAHS.038A  "VEGFA" "VWF"    NA    NA     NA       NA     
PAHS.084A  "ULK2"  "UVRAG"  NA    NA     NA       NA
```

I want to use `write.table()` to write the table to a tab delimited text file, but instead of having `NA`'s, I just want to start a new line whenever a row reaches an `NA`. Is there an easy way to do that?

I tried setting the NAs to "" but I still had tabs to indicate the missing values. I would just like a new line at that point instead of tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because write.table is designed to output regular objects (data.frames and matrices) with some sort of separator, you will probably get more traction with one of `cat`,  `write` or `writeLines`:

```
txt <- data.frame(a="a", b="b", c=NA, d=NA  ,e=NA)
txt <- txt[rep(1,10),]  # 10 copies
apply(txt,1,function(x) cat(x[!is.na(x)], "\n", file="out.txt", append=TRUE ))
```

Comment: +1. This is nice. Following up, to get a tab-delimited file, replace `function(x)` in the final line with this: `cat(paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse="\t"), sep="\n", file="out.txt", append=TRUE)`.

Comment: Tabs. I forgot the tabs. Thanks for fixing that omission.